# How do you get the drawer to slide in after clicking a menu item in Aurelia UI

Tags: aurelia-ui-framework

On the demo page when you click on a menu item in the drawer it closes.

In the code I could't find a trigger event attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `close-on-click` attribute.

```
<ui-drawer close-on-click>
...
</ui-drawer>
```